# Toggle Grease Pencil "Use Lights" value using Python

Tags: python, lighting, grease-pencil

I'd like to toggle the checkbox shown in the image with the Python editor in Blender, but can't find anything in the documentation that matches what I'm looking for. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
bpy.data.grease_pencils['GPencil'].layers['GP_Layer'].use_lights = False
```

The grease pencil object is:

```
gp = bpy.data.grease_pencils['GPencil']
```

Its 'GP_Layer' layer:

```
gp_layer = gp.layers['GP_Layer']
```

And its use lights property:

```
gp_layer.use_lights
```